# Unable to start shell: Failed to start pty: fork/exec /usr/bin/sh: operation not permitted

Tags: go, aws-ssm

I'm trying to install and run AWS SSM Agent under non-root user on on-premise environment. For example, I brought up the amazon-ssm-agent process as ec2-user on OS. No problem with the registration and I could see the Ping status as 'online' in AWS SSM console. However, when I tried to start session against the instance through session manager, it always failed and prompts error like this:

```
"Output": "\n----------ERROR-------\nUnable to start shell: Failed to start pty: fork/exec /usr/bin/sh: operation not permitted
```

And the related source code snippet is this:

```
func StartPty(
    log log.T,
    shellProps mgsContracts.ShellProperties,
    isSessionLogger bool,
    config agentContracts.Configuration,
    plugin *ShellPlugin) (err error) {

    log.Info("Starting pty")
    //Start the command with a pty
    var cmd *exec.Cmd
    if strings.TrimSpace(shellProps.Linux.Commands) == "" || isSessionLogger {
        cmd = exec.Command("sh")
    } else {
        commandArgs := append(utility.ShellPluginCommandArgs, shellProps.Linux.Commands)
        cmd = exec.Command("date", commandArgs...)
    }

....

    ptyFile, err = pty.Start(cmd)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Failed to start pty: %s\n", err)
        return fmt.Errorf("Failed to start pty: %s\n", err)
    }
```

Initially I though maybe it's permission issue with that shell binary file. But there's nothing wrong with that and everybody could run the shell command.

Does anybody know what's going on here and have any advice on how to figure it out? thanks

Btw, AWS SSM agent source code is based on Go programming language.

Comment: Just missed one clue i noticed, if i start ssm agent as root, everything is working fine. So according to this, I'm kinda sure that it has something to do with some particular files. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to find them out.